# Pass JSON request of array values in android

Tags: android

I need to pass HTTP JSON request as array values as "Id":["13","14","15","17","27","29" ] in android.How could i do that?I tried like this "Id": { "\"13\"".. }

Thanks.

My answer:

Finally i got it.

for (String sstring : new String[] { "1","2" }) {
    Carray.put(sstring);
}

Thanks for the support.

Comment: what you tried? Post some code

Comment: you must search before posting question read this tutorial http://www.androidhive.info/2012/01/android-json-parsing-tutorial/

Comment: @Sanjay Have you tried anything? If yes then show us your code. And yes, Do you know about [JSONObject](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONObject.html) and [JSONArray](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONArray.html)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
JSONObject Root = new JSONObject();String Data1 = "[13,14,15,17,27,29]";
try 
{
Root.put("Id",  Data1);Log.e("try",Root.toString());
} 
catch (JSONException e) 
{
e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Using Above Code You Get This Type Of Output//OutPut :- {"Id":["13","14","13","15","27","29"]}